# How to get total number of non-repetitive substrings?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Suppose I have `string str = "aabaa"`

Its non repetitive substrings are

1. a
2. b
3. aa
4. ab
5. ba
6. aab
7. aba
8. baa
9. aaba
10. abaa
11. aabaa

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Have you tried to do it yourself? Are you stuck on a particular part? Otherwise, I've done my fair share of coding exercises.

Comment: Actually this question was asked in a contest on hackerrank ..  First and formost i am not able to write  code for   printing sub strings.. So please tell me how  i will print substrings

Comment: You can't take any substring? Use this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Thanks @Pavel , But how will you compare these sub stings with all others to print no repetitive string with minimum time complexity?

Comment: @MohammadChandAlam, if you doesn't have long strings, you can simply add each substring you found to array. To don't add duplicates just check every time if new string already exist in array. It will take O(N^3) memory and O(N^4) time. If you want to do it more effective, use Z-function (http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107)

Comment: @Pavel Basically this problem was related to minimize time complexity .. String was upto length 100 character..

Comment: @MohammadChandAlam, 100 chars isn't very much, but if you want an optimal solution, try using Z-function.

Comment: Thank you @Pavel I will try to use Z-function.

Comment: @MohammadChandAlam You could use a `std::set<std::string>` or `std::unordered_set<std::string>` instead of an array.  Then you don't need to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Compute the [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) and the longest common prefix array thereof.

   ```
   a
    1
   aa
    2
   aabaa
    1
   abaa
    0
   baa
   ```
2. Return `(n+1)n/2`, the number of substring bounds, minus the sum of the longest common prefix array.

   ```
   (5+1)5/2 - (1+2+1+0) = 15 - 4 = 11.
   ```